# CSS transitions regarding binary properties (eg visibility)

Tags: css, css-transitions, visibility

I found a strange behavior when transitioning between visibility `hidden` and `visible`. It seems like when going to `visible`, it immediately becomes `visible` at the start of the transition duration. But going back to `hidden`, it waits until the transition duration has completed before disappearing.

What's the reason for this? Is this something I can rely on, or should I explicitly set their transition delays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is because that is the recommended implementation for transitioning the `visible` property:

From [the W3 for CSS Transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animtype-visibility):

> visibility: if one of the values is ‘visible’, interpolated as a discrete step where values of the timing function between 0 and 1 map to ‘visible’ and other values of the timing function (which occur only at the start/end of the transition or as a result of ‘cubic-bezier()’ functions with Y values outside of [0, 1]) map to the closer endpoint; if neither value is ‘visible’ then not interpolable.

Basically, `visible` is used whenever the transition percentage is not 0.00 (or 1.00). So, if the transition percentage is, say, 10% (0.1), then it is visible. That is why it becomes visible immediately. The other values aren't recognized until the transition is fully complete, because visible is used during the transition.

Depending on your use-case, you can use `transition-delay`, you can use a keyframe `animation`, you can transition the `opacity` property, or you can try to use `cubic-bezier` functions.

Comment: Thank you! I came across that same description on mozilla, but I didn't understand it.